# Add a dictionary as a value to another dictionary with the same key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the following -

```
parent_key : {child : 1, child :2}
```

I have another dictionary with the same format -

```
parent_key : {child : 3, child :2}
```

Both have the same parent key and same child keys.I need to get the output like the following -

```
parent_key : {{child : 1, child :2},{child : 3, child :2}}
```

If I use update() method, it simply updates the keys with the latest value but I need in the format I specified. Kindly help!

Comment: Is the output supposed to be a dict or a list? Your code examples are a little confusing.

Comment: your output is a set of dicts, which is not valid.

Comment: It does not make any sense because Python dictionaries don't support duplicate keys!

Answer (score 1):

Your output represents a set of dictionaries:

```
parent_key : {{child : 1, child :2},{child : 3, child :2}}
```

which is invalid. I'm also assuming those are not actually duplicate keys and you just replaced every key with `child`. Otherwise, the final result is even more invalid, since dictionaries can't have duplicate keys.

Instead, I suggest creating this structure instead:

```
{parent_key : [{child1 : 1, child2 :2}, {child1 : 3, child2 :2}]}
```

Which collects each inner child dictionary into a list, which seems to be closest to what you were trying to achieve.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {"a": {"b": 1, "c": 2}}
d2 = {"a": {"b": 3, "c": 2}}

final_d = defaultdict(list)
for d in (d1, d2):
    for k, v in d.items():
        final_d[k].append(v)

print(final_d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [{'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 2}]})

print(dict(d))
# {'a': [{'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 2}]}
```

The above uses a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists to aggregate the dictionaries into a list.

You could also achieve a nested dictionary result like this:

```
{parent_key : {child1: [1, 3], child2: [2, 2]}}
```

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {"a": {"b": 1, "c": 2}}
d2 = {"a": {"b": 3, "c": 2}}

final_d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for d in (d1, d2):
    for k1, v1 in d.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            final_d[k1][k2].append(v2)

print(final_d)
# {'a': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [1, 3], 'c': [2, 2]})}

print({k: dict(v) for k, v in final_d.items()})
# {'a': {'b': [1, 3], 'c': [2, 2]}}
```

**Note:** `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so it acts as a normal dictionary. I've just printed two versions with defaultdict and without for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
dic_arr = [{'a' : 2, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 6},  
             {'a' : 5, 'b' : 7, 'c' : 8}, 
             {'d' : 10}] 

res = {} 
for sub in dic_arr: 
    for key, val in sub.items():  
        res.setdefault(key, []).append(val) 

print(str(res))
```